# Should "Thank you" comments be flagged?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

When commenting, the box tells you to avoid "Thank you" comments.

In my opinion, "Thank you" comments are useless, and should therefore be flagged as 'obsolete'.

So, I just flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990419/is-it-possible-to-override-a-base-method-with-a-more-specific-by-return-type-m/23990524#23990524) and expected it to be helpful, but it was declined.

> Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

This comment is useless, since thanking can be done by upvoting, and for telling it is exactly what OP wanted, we have the accept button.

Question:

- Should "Thank you" comments be flagged?
- If so, why was this flag declined?

Comment: While the comment is not especially constructive in this form, flagging it causes more work than simply ignoring it. You're creating work for the mods who have to handle these flags, and I'd figure they have better things to do than cleaning up "thank you" comments...

Comment: Historical note: This question relates to a declined "obsolete" comment flag which should have been a "too chatty" comment flag. In 2017 [the comment flag options were changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352274/1364007) so the "not constructive", "obsolete" and "too chatty" flags were combined into one "no longer needed" flag. The flag being declined due to it being an "obsolete" flag no longer applies, but the fact that "Thank you" comments [shouldn't be posted in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and should be flagged (as "no longer needed") remains.

Comment: I would like to explain why I do not agree with the reasoning of @I4mpi's comment. Some answers are really extensive without containing any references to "good" sources. Those answers could easily contain some elements that are wrong. I then search for any comments indicating that something in the post is wrong or comments which elaborate on the answer. Some well received answers receive a lot of comments (just came by one with 40) and when a lot of comments are "thanks" or jokes, it makes the comments not worth the time reading anymore in my opinion.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, typically we do consider these types of comments as noise and should be removed.  If you see them, then flag them as such.

However, you flagged this specific comment as "Obsolete" which doesn't apply to "Thank you" comments. "Obsolete" flags should be used for code that is in comments that has been edited into a post, or for comments like *What database are you using?* and then the OP edits a tag. Since you used "Obsolete", this could be why the flag was declined.

In the future, when flagging "Thank you" comments, I would suggest using "Too Chatty".  Using the correct flag is helpful on comments as well.

I've now removed the comment.

Comment: Do ["me too" comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449541/android-application-restarts-when-opened-by-clicking-the-application-icon#comment30619999_18449541) also warrant the same action?

Comment: @Sam: I guess so.

Comment: @Sam: Yeah, I want to know that too.

Comment: I can understand that I could see like noise comment but I feel my self so gratifying when someone I helped tell me "Thanks, it works perfectly". It is jus a burst of motivation and a bit of education for the other part, something we can't loose. The answer that helped someone that said that "thanks" could mean days of work that you avoid to him, don't forget it!

Comment: @taryn This is the question I found from searches on how to handle these questions.  I assume it is the dupe target?  The "Too Chatty" reason doesn't appear to exist anymore and instead I believe the auto-delete happens now on "It's no longer needed."  What do you think the best way to convey the current best practice?  Edit the answer with the new selection (?), although it might not make sense in historical on what action took place for this specific question.

Answer (score 26):

The `Upvote` isn't the same as "thank you".

We were humans, who got (hopefully) some upbringing from the parents.

But, I understand (and welcome) the SO approach - building an "NONSOCIAL question/answer database", what reduces the entropy of the universe.

So when the SO wants to suppress the social behavior (and it is OK) **should supress** the personal parts of the answer. Simply, DON'T show **who** is the question/answer poster.

Several times I have heard from colleagues: *this answer from {some_nick} will be sure good,* only because he helped much times in the past, regardless of the *actual quality* of the answer.

From the "database" of point of view,

- The users don't need to know, **WHO** gave the answer, simply, want get ***an*** answer.
- users will upvoting the ANSWERs (and NOT as it is currently - they're **rewarding the person**, who made the answer)

So, if SO should be "a database of questions/answers"

- should NOT show the "person name who wrote the answer" (enough to have an link to his profile)
- should NOT show his current reputation and avatar

Things as the *person's* reputation, name and picture **are pointless from the view of the answer quality.** Enough an simple [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632407/jm666) link, without the picture, reputation and name (nick).

Everything is remain as was. Persons will still gains reputations, anybody can read their profile clicking to the "answered" link, and so on.

On the other side - understand - when someone **rewarding a person**, it is normal to say "thanx" (at least in the culture of my country).

Comment: On popular questions you often see threads of 'thank you' comments. This makes reading the relevant comments somewhat impossible. I think there is a rule to prevent this, and that rule is applied everywhere to keep it fair.

Comment: @PatrickHofman i agree with the rule (mostly) ;). I wrote the above as an "analysis" how the SO can more suppress the "social" feeling" of the site.

Comment: If I really want to thank someone I will post a comment and remove it shortly after. That will prevent the thread from cluttering, and the receiver will still get it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman fair enough! It is new for me than the deleted comment still arrives. ;) Going to check my "thanx-like" comments.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

In order to reduce "noise" - i would flag this comment.

As any answer is providing some aid to someone, the "thank you" is expected.