# Thanks in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

I am pretty new to Stack Exchange in general, and I don't have 15 reputation points on any Stack Exchange site — this means I can't upvote answers. If I receive a really helpful, in-depth answer, is it objectively wrong for me to comment on their answer with a *"Thanks, I really appreciate it!!"*?

The placeholder in the comment text box says *Avoid comments like "+1" or "Thanks"*, and I have read some of the other Meta questions (like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged) one), and everyone seems to hate seeing 'thank you' comments, but what about in a case like mine? Without [PMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_message), there is no other way to thank someone for their time, and it seems... odd to me, I guess.

Comment: You can get 10 more rep really fast: Each good edit suggestion which is accepted (that's way easier than it should be, no hurdle at all), and each time you accept an answer, gives you 2. There are more than enough posts to edit. A question upvote gives you 5 and an answer upvote 10.

Comment: Alright, T***ks. Time to brainstorm some good questions, then.

Comment: Here is some good news: thus far, you *are* writing good questions. Browse the questions with your same tags and see if you can answer one or two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should "Thank you" comments be flagged?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged)

Comment: I am referring to the specific situation wherein a user doesn't have enough rep to upvote. Not a duplicate, imo

Comment: Thank you comments are not appropriate, whether you have sufficient rights to vote or not.

Comment: (... not on meta ...)

Comment: @eddie_cat [Reasons for doing that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147007/what-to-do-if-an-answer-has-too-many-thanks-comments). And because [so] is [not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362473/how-do-i-respond-to-assertions-that-stack-overflow-is-just-like-a-forum).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You thank someone by marking the answer as being correct (checking the checkmark next to the answer). This will give your rep a +2 boost.

Ask good questions (that get up-votes), accept answers and provide good answers to other questions and you'll soon have enough reputation to vote.

Thank you comments are considered 'noise' - [Should "Thank you" comments be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1)

Answer (score 17):

I disagree slightly. I agree that posting a 'Thank you' comment on a years old answer you've stumbled across is noise, but I think it's perfectly fine to thank someone who answered your question - after all someone just went out of their way to help you. Yes, ticking the one that solved your problem is the right thing to do but what if you got more than one answer?

Generally I

- reply to every answer to my questions with a 'thank you' and some comment on the answer, whether it was helpful or not
- up-vote all helpful answers (that didn't just repeat part of my question)
- tick the one that actually solved my problem, or the most helpful one that solved my problem if there were more than one

i.e. there are a handful of answers I've gotten that get a 'thank you, but...' and no up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why it would be 'logical' to ask people not to post "thank you" comments, it is a very scientific way of approaching this community, and Stack Overflow caters mainly to people with a more scientific way of viewing the world. Doing this keeps the site looking neat and organised (which good coders should be aiming to do with their code, commit messages, etc.) and allows people to get to the information they need quickly.

However, if you visit more 'humanities' based stack exchange sites (e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/), I believe that, in general, you encounter less 'purely scientific' people who value conversation and encouragement over keeping things neat and organised. It is just a different way of viewing the world and approaching community.

I personally like getting 'thanks' comments because I'm not a robot and it encourages me to continue posting on here to help other people out. Maybe in their attempts to keep things organised, the moderators will inadvertently destroy the enthusiasm of the community. Only the stats will tell.

Comment: Accepting / upvoting proper answers is SO's way of saying "Thanks". _"Thanks"_-comments are simply noise, and should be removed. Besides, was it really necessary to answer a question this old?

Comment: @cerbrus Yes which is exactly why I began by initially pointing out that by using them it keeps the site clean (which is what a scientific community wants right?). Interesting that other 'less scientific' stack exchange sites don't have the same placeholder text asking people not to say 'thanks', which either proves my point, or is just because it hasn't been rolled out yet.

Comment: @Cerbrus I was about to ask this question myself but then realised it had already been answered, so wanted to give my opinion on it. Or do you think that discussion should stop merely because it was discussed a year ago, don't you think that progress is made through continuous and ongoing discussion?

Comment: What you say about the other "humanities"-focused Stack Exchange sites having different standards is not correct. The mission is pushed by Stack Exchange and the engine that runs the sites is designed around it. It has nothing to do with scientific or technical people, but rather with our goal of creating an encyclopedia of online knowledge. They are Q&A sites, not discussion forums. Yes, the individual members (probably) are not robots and (probably) like interpersonal engagement, but that creates distractions and noise on the site. You don't see comments on Wikipedia, either.

Comment: It isn't about having different standards, it is about understanding potentially very different audiences. It is the same as how one has to modify a product slightly based on audiences from different countries, e.g. Zootopia being called Zootropolis to cater to the UK audience: http://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/disney-zootopia-now-zootropolis/ Understanding your audience/user base is just business common sense

Comment: And by the way, just to make it clear, when I'm working I much prefer not having to sift through the noise of 'thanks' comments to find an answer to something that sometimes is very time sensitive (despite enjoying receiving thanks comments in addition to up-votes), I'm just suggesting that for some people, a bit more encouragement can actually stimulate engagement. I like the feature on the site that hides these comments and shows the most relevant ones, and think this is potentially better than asking people not to submit them

Comment: Well, that's what people predicted (and some people in the Stack Exchange community team were afraid of) when they started launching non-technical Q&A sites. But it has worked out pretty well. [History.SE] and [Philosophy.SE] are two examples that come to mind. Even [English.SE], as you mention in your answer: moderators there will delete "thanks" comments, just like they do on Stack Overflow. It's not like you're punished for leaving them or anything, but the same cleanup effort is always afoot, aiming to turn the site into a well-manicured garden, not a half-screen full of chat history.

Comment: @timhc22: My point is that we _shouldn't_ stimulate this kind of engagement. It's noise.

Comment: @CodyGray interesting, thanks for pointing that out, I wasn't aware that people were afraid of this initially, and it is interesting to hear that 'thanks'  comments are removed on those sites too, I was just interested to see that the comment box placeholder text was different on the different sites, and thought that maybe this was as a result of catering to very different audiences.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not disagreeing, what I'm suggesting is that will 'overall engagement' be damaged by requesting this (and is this the reason it isn't the placeholder in the comments boxes on the more 'discussion based' as oppose to 'fact based' stack exchange sites)

Comment: Maybe the solution is 2 comment boxes 'Add a thanks' and 'Add a comment', and then people who feel the need to, can 'thanks' to their hearts content haha. (Not sure if this would be good UX though)

Comment: @timhc22: You're still not getting it. _"Thanks"_ comments shouldn't be on SO. Period. No _"But..., If..."_, etc. They don't belong on this site. If you want to thank someone for a good answer, ___vote___ for that answer

Comment: @cerberus I completely get it and agree that I don't want to see 'thanks' comments whilst I'm looking for answers (as pointed out previously). I'm pointing out the fact that audiences are very different, and trying to discuss whether there is a way of 'filtering' noise whilst maintaining the overall enthusiasm and engagement of the user base

Comment: @Cerbrus by 'engagement' I mean a more ongoing 'long term' commitment to being part of a contributing user base, and I am wondering and discussing whether 'micro engagement' (such as small 'thank yous') plays a part in keeping people actively engaged and wanting to contribute more actually useful stuff (but obviously we need the un-useful stuff filtered out).

Comment: I know that 'upvotes' is pretty good 'micro-engagement' anyway, and it definitely keeps me contributing, but Facebook have definitely realised that moving beyond mere 'likes' (and adding other reactions) has been an important way of keeping their user base engaged

Comment: Sometimes if I have been searching for an answer to something for a long time, merely giving someone an upvote just doesn't really express the gratitude in the way I want it to (which is why people probably feel the need to write 'thank you' as well). Maybe there should be a 'buy them a beer' button as well ;)

Comment: Facebook is a social networking site. SO isn't. You reward a user for a good answer, and that's it. If you _really_ want to reward a user more, you can always hand out a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: Sure, but there is ALWAYS going to be a social element involved because people are involved and people are (usually) inherently social beings who like to interact with other people, and I believe this is evidenced by the ongoing need for some people to post 'thank you' as well as give an 'upvote'. Posting 'thank you' is more convenient than giving a bounty (can do it in less clicks), maybe there should be a button for people to 'give a gratitude bounty' or something, maybe this would quell the undesirable 'thanks'

Comment: *Only the stats will tell*. 10 million questions, 8 thousand questions a day... I'd say they have.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sure at the moment it is doing well (and I don't doubt it will continue to), but analysing long terms user engagement trends over time and studying how they correlate with decisions that have been made (e.g. UI and UX) is sensible and can give valuable feedback on how to improve a product and keep the community engaged/encourage them to engage more