# "Thanks a lot! Thx!" comment - Flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, comment-flags

I generally flag comments **only** "thanking" other people as "too chatty" (see for example [Thanks in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267490/thanks-in-a-comment), [Should "Thank you" comments be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged)).

And what now follows is yet another "why was my flag declined" question. The comment was:

> Thanks a lot! Thx!

Was I wrong in flagging the comment?

Comment: We have a couple of new mods, myself included, I may have fat-fingered it? Looks familiar, probably me. You're right, that should have been good.

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to know if it was a genuine decline - which would mean I have to start thinking when flagging "Thanks" - or a mistake.

Comment: My apologies...

Comment: He's already screwed up. GET THE BACKUP MOD!

Comment: Where's my torch and pitchfork? :)

Comment: @AaronHall I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @AaronHall Well in any case, thanks for taking care of it!

Comment: I was not aware of this policy, and I've been around for a while o_O. I must have dozens of cmmts like the ones described. Guess I'll stop now, but it feels kind of rude to not thank when a person made a real effort to help...

Comment: @Gabriel Why stop? You want to thank people making an effort and I want to flag. Everybody wins (except the moderators having to deal with the flags, but they don't count :-)).

Comment: @Gabriel You can upvote.

Comment: I do. But I also like to thank whoever is using their time to help me.

Comment: QGabriel Better upvoting / accepting the answer then thanking. Isn't it stupid to write a "thank you" comment and not upvoting / accepting the answer? I've seen that several times.

Comment: Personally I like the "Thanks".  Rep is nice, thanks are also nice (with less rep.)

Comment: @Gabriel But what can be more valuable and rewarding than magic internet points?

Comment: IMHO, "thanks [...]" is processed by our monkey brains more intimately than an upvote. I've had some bad experiences in SO, so I'd like to encourage brief personal interactions that are non-breaking to workflow.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You were not wrong. Every new moderator is required to make at least one mistake to confirm that they are, in fact, human, just like the rest of us.

Aaron Hall has passed the test. You can rest assured that electing him was the right choice and that more mistakes will be made in the future. Hopefully none quite as fatal as declining a "too chatty" flag on a "Thanks!" comment.

Comment: This answer may or may not be entirely serious.

Comment: I need to decline a proper flag asap, then. ;)

Comment: Moderators...human? *[citation required]*

Comment: Is removing a comment thanking someone really a good use of moderator time? It's not like you're looking at a derailed comment chain that's starting to distract from the post. If there are other problems around it, by all means, clean it up, but this strikes me as a complete waste of time otherwise. (Yes, I'm aware of the prevailing vitriol against such notes from a number of high rep users; I still don't see why they think this is a problem worth sinking time into.)

Comment: @jpmc26: Removing a comment thanking someone doesn't take more than a second or two. Those seconds don't add up to a whole lot. If I don't feel like handling flags on these comments, though, I'll just ignore them. Either enough people are disciplined to flag the same comment and it goes away on its own, or another moderator can come along and handle it. Assuming they don't fat-finger of course... but even if they do, I agree it really isn't worth pursuing. It's just a comment flag, and it's just a comment. See a "Thanks!" comment? Flag it, and forget about it.

Comment: However, sometimes the Thank you does add to the answer. For me, it further proves the legitimacy of the answer provided. A lot of times you'll see a few answers, about equally voted, and if one has a thank you then I'll weigh that in as well. Even the accepted answer sometimes isn't the right one.

Comment: lol - like a little mod captcha

Comment: Does this qualify Aaron for the Not a Robot badge?

Comment: Well, there goes my faith in the Turing test. What's the point of fallible robotic overlords?