# Why was this comment flag declined?

Tags: support, flags, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

I recently flagged [this comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/40831203/issues-with-fixed-html-header-using-jquery/40834184#comment68885902_40834184), because it contained nothing except the end of the answer that it was on.

It was declined without any message. Why?

Comment: First off, you can't get a decline message with comment flags, and secondly, probably because you didn't flag with a message like "contained nothing except the end of the answer". Mods aren't omniscient.

Comment: @hichris123 I _did_ use a custom flag though.

Comment: With what message?

Comment: "part of answer"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I misread your comment flag; I thought someone had once again flagged a comment as "**should** be part of the answer", meaning that the comment should have been an edit but was not.

I'm always reluctant to remove such comments unless they are quite a bit older, and I rarely have time to go and make that edit; that'd be the community's job, so I always dismiss such flags.

However, you meant that the comment was merely obsolete, and I should have deleted the comment; I've done so now. My fault.

For future reference:

- Comment flags can't be responded to; we can either delete the comment, edit the comment (both mark the flag as helpful), or reject the flag. Nothing else, no message options are included here. Comments are a dime a dozen, after all.
- If a comment is obsolete, it's easier for us if you flagged it as *obsolete*, rather than use a custom flag. I can process those faster.
- We process hundreds and hundreds of comment flags a day, so occasionally we slip up. Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

Sigh.

Unlike [the previous incident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338489/thanks-a-lot-thx-comment-flag-declined/338504#338504), this was not part of any test — this was handled by another experienced moderator.

I don't know why your flag was declined. It's not like it was a regular "obsolete" flag with no context — you did specifically state that the comment was unnecessary because it was just a copy of the last sentence in the answer (by the answer poster, might I add). I would have deleted the comment for this very reason.

Comment: "My answer is that I don't have an answer"

Comment: @Stephen Leppik: I'd like to see you satisfied by any explanation the moderator who handled your flag gives. It's more than likely they just didn't pay close attention. Alternatively, I could put the blame on you for not even putting effort into writing a complete sentence in your comment flag and expecting us to decipher context out of a three-word phrase (like I did in my answer) in a matter of seconds.

Comment: In retrospect, I'm not sure why I went with the 3-word statement. I was actually considering something longer… whatever.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Moderators handle a really high volume of flags on SO. Anything you can do to make the problem clear to a moderator so that they don't have to visit the question and try to figure out which issue you're calling out makes our lives a lot easier.

Comment: @meagar that'll be my accepted answer right there if you post it :)

Comment: @StephenLeppik To quote the flag description: *Be specific and detailed!*