# Tooltip for comment flags displays the wrong reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, comment-flags

I flagged a comment on [Java application gives random outputs of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25392656/3453226) with reason *too chatty*.

[image]

When moving the cursor over the flag icon, it says *you've flagged this comment as unconstructive, offensive, or spam*.

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from flagging "thank you" comments of OP, or, in case of an answer, the poster of the answer. You are making StackOverflow worse by discouraging friendliness. I hope that the reviewer had the sense to deny this flag.

Comment: @Kay A comment getting removed doesn't necessarily mean the comment shouldn't have been posted. I think it's perfectly fine that the comment was posted, I would have been happy with such a comment had it been my edit. But it benefits at most one person, who in all likelihood by now has either already read it, or isn't going to, so there is little sense in keeping the comment around forever.

Comment: @Kay: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FIXED**

It seems they have followed [my suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269267/tooltip-for-comment-flags-displays-the-wrong-reason#comment82355_269288).

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Basically, it is really just trying to say "you've flagged this comment". As you can tell by the multiple options, it isn't trying to be exact - and it also isn't trying to list all possible options that might exist; simply to give an indication of what flagging means. I'm open to possible rephrasing...

Comment: "You've flagged this comment"

Comment: @cheesemacfly yeah, that was the simplest fix I could think of too; I'm tempted to prefer "you have flagged this comment" - semantically identical, but reads better, IMO

Comment: I think that would be enough information for a tooltip and if you don't remember why you flagged the comment, the history in your profile tells you what was the reason.

Comment: _you've already flagged this comment_