# There should be an answer accepting box for new users

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

Sometimes when I answer the question, it's a new user.  This question is their first, and it's decent.

After answering, sometimes they leave a comment, saying "thanks!", "thanks you", ect.  **But the answer is never accepted**.  This is probably due to confusion on how SO works.

In my opinion, there should be a little dialog box saying something like "This answer solve you problem? Click the check mark."  This way, the new user would be aware what to do if a question has solved their problem.

I even made a little example:

[[image: Example](Click for full)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx7GR.png)

In this example, **only the top answer** would have the box.  Only putting it on the top answer would be effective in many ways, because:

- The user is for sure going to see the first answer.
- Answers that are sorted by "Votes" will surface to the top, so they're more likely to accept a good answer.
- This method works with practically any sorting.

Also, please note that this box would only appear for their first (and second?) question.  After a question has been accepted, this box will never appear again.

Comment: Accepting an answer means that that is the answer which helped the OP the most (it solved his problem).  However, this is not always the most upvoted answer.  Lots of questions here on SO have the accepted answer and then another answer with over twice the upvotes.  What would you do in this case?

Comment: No, coaxing the user into accepting any particular answer is bad (who remembers the accept rate fiasco?)

Comment: I wouldn't consider it "coaxing", perhaps the dialog box could jump down to the next answer, if they keep scrolling.  Also keep in mind it says "Did this answer solve you problem?", if it didn't, they probably wont check it.

Comment: Doesn't the system already notify them when they're commenting? Something along the lines of "If this answer helped you, consider accepting it"? Or is that for something else? It's been a long time since I've seen such a message...

Comment: @animuson:  I *think* it does something like that.  It'd make sense for it to (and I do recall seeing it quite a long time ago).

Comment: @Xero Your suggestion is an imperative. It says "Click the checkmark." I would reword it. Since it has a tutorial-like nature, I would imagine that users would click it simply because the dialog is telling them to.

Comment: @animuson The system shows this reminder when the user upvoted an answer. But new users often don't have enough rep to vote by the time they get  the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

This implies that the most upvoted answer is the most useful to the OP, and this is certainly not always the case.  It also implies that every question *must* have an accepted answer, and this isn't necessarily the case either.

Users are certainly encouraged to accept an answer - they even get a little bit of rep for it! - but that doesn't mean that they are *forced* to.

Also, what about the answers that simply *don't* answer the question in a way that the OP wanted?  Why should they be forced to accept something that they don't agree with?

A long time ago we had [accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/175248) on people's accounts who were asking a question, and this imposed an opinion on people - that those who had a lower accept rate were somehow less deserving of having their question answered.  It ultimately led to it being hidden from view, which is what the top of the discussion that I linked to talks about.

That whole discussion above is probably why I don't feel that such a box would be worth the time.  It'd feel like it makes users do something that, while they have the option to, and while they receive awesome kudos for doing, they're not obligated to do at all.

Comment: Although I agree with everything said in here.  The point of the box is to tell users that if the answered solved their question, it should be accepted.  It's no supposed to give a demanding feel.

Comment: It's fairly common that somebody leaves a comment saying something like "thanks! this is exactly what I needed!", but does not accept the answer. I believe the idea of this proposal is that there should be clearer help showing people that they **can** accept answers, and how to do that. They should certainly not be forced.

Answer (score 1):

> After answering, sometimes they leave a comment, saying "thanks!",
>   "thanks you", ect. But the answer is never accepted.

If this happens, you can flag those comments as [too chatty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged). It doesn't hurt to link them to either:

- the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), which has a brief explanation on accepting answers:

  > Good answers are voted up and **rise to the top**.
  >
  > *The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find.*
  >
  > The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".
  >
  > *Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.*
- the help center, [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
- or the MSE FAQ, [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Currently, the tool-tip when you hover over the checkmark says:

> Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the
>   most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)

...which sounds very similar to your proposal. However, I don't agree with your current wording.

> This answer solve your question? Click the checkmark.

This removes choice/agency from the user because it looks like a command and especially if it's supposed to be a tutorial, they're more likely to click it since it tells them to.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> It also doesn't follow the spirit of the other help text which suggests that the user should accept the answer that's *most useful* to them, and not just any random one.

I would suggest rewording it to make it clearer that:

- Accepting is not an imperative, it's a choice. They don't have to accept an answer if they don't want to.
- By possibly adding a link from the list above.

Like [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277723/there-should-be-an-answer-accepting-box-for-new-users#comment121146_277723) says, there's already a feature built-in says something along the lines of "If this answer helped you, consider accepting it?".

Comment: I don't you're supposed to accept my answer in [meta-tag:feature-request]s.