# Banner to alert there's a more upvoted answer than the accepted one?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I'm afraid someone else *must have* said this before, but I'm not founding any question - so here I go.

I see *lots* of questions (usually kind of old ones) with some accepted and kind-of-upvoted answer (score 15+) that I say *this can't be the real answer*, and then find the next answer has *way more score* (50+) and usually *is* the real answer up to date.

There are other cases in which I don't think that fast that there should be a better answer - and maybe I don't find it until some time has gone.

I've also remember having read that, as far as the person who asked seems it's a working answer, it has to remain accepted and get the first place *even if the community thinks other answer is better*. I have no problem with that - it really *makes sense* - but I think the best upvoted answer deserves it's attention, too. It currently gets it in the form of a *really upvoted* comment on the accepted answer, but it could be better.

**How about some tiny message before the accepted answer warning *"There's an answer with more upvotes than the accepted one"*?**

I'll let the designers and those smart people the ideas of how to do it.

PS: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252015/overriding-accepted-answers) is some related discussion. All of this has been triggered by questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting) - just an example, not an opinion about that.

Comment: I don't like the idea mostly because it feels like it would be trying to pressure the OP into accepting a different answer than what they wanted to accept. At least, I think some people asking questions might feel this way especially if they are new to the topic and/or SO. This is besides the fact that an OP has the right to accept any answer he wishes and the more upvoted answer already gets credit by gaining rep from the upvotes.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277723/there-should-be-an-answer-accepting-box-for-new-users

Comment: "and then find the next answer".  Yes, that's how it works, you don't have to go to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted, it's a good topic to discuss. Anyways, in the case of your example it seems there were multiple answers to the user's Android question but the one that helped the asker was the accepted one. Just because the other answer helped more people it doesn't mean it helped the OP.

Comment: +1. This is a good idea. I'm used to scrolling to make sure there's not a better answer (especially when I don't like the accepted answer), but newer users may not think to do that. This would be a nice reminder.

Comment: I'm not against keeping the accepted answer first - just remind _the community doesn't seem to agree with OP_.

Answer (score -2):

I think this would be a great feature.

I have been caught multiple times by answers with outdated, more complicated, wrong answers just to find a better answer below with many more votes.

"The higher-voted answers are not always correct." comment in Karolis Koncevičius's answer doesn't really hold as the marker wouldn't say "There is a correct answer below".

Answer (score -3):

I don't really agree. If any changes were to be made in that direction I would even suggest doing the opposite - not publicly displaying vote counts for a certain period of time or before the answer is accepted.

The higher-voted answers are not always correct. I can offer two scenarios encountered in my limited experience to illustrate the point:

1. Votes do not always represent quality. There are people who see anything that looks "professional" (in other words has a lot of codes and headers) and upvotes merely for that. Also I saw some instances where the user with high rep and gold badges gets upvoted more merely for answering (even if his answer is short and slightly of the point).
2. Sometimes the most upvoted answers don't even address the question. For example user asks: how to do **X** with **Y**. And the answers flood saying that one should never use **X** together with **Y** but rather use **Z**. Other users sometimes jump in and upvote such answers. But they don't even answer the question.

These are the ones I encountered that are quite common. I am sure there are many other situations when most-upvoted answer is not acceptable.

And so in my view your suggestion would make things worse. Shifting the bias of the original poster towards agreeing with the mass even further. I think him seeing the counts is pressure enough to think twice before accepting an answer with 1 vote when there are two others with ~10.

Comment: I don't really have an opinion about the time factor and that. I'm not even trying to imply that the most upvoted answer is better than the accepted one. I'm just seeing lots of cases in which that holds true, and there surely are lot of other in which not. My point is just to emphasise that there is another answer to which the community is giving traction, so the user can choose.

Comment: If I was trying to slice bread with a spoon I'd probably benefit more from an answer telling me to use a knife instead than from anything else.

Comment: I think your scenario is not the intent of this feature (at least as I see it). I would expect it to work like this: OP asks question. Answer is posted. OP accepts answer. Some time later, better answer comes in. OP doesn't care or is no longer around. Better answer eventually gets more votes than accepted answer. From then on, banner appears above accepted answer, stating "Warning: one or more answers have a higher vote count than the accepted answer." Key point: **the warning banner should not appear if the OP accepted an answer with fewer votes!** (It should only show for late answers.)