# Would you like an employee to delete these filtered "thank you" comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

**Delete comments that were posted *prior to 2015* and**

- contain the text "***thank***" *(so picks up both "thanks" and "thank you")*
- are ***less than 25 characters*** in length *(filters out comments that may contain "thank" along with possibly useful information)*
- have a **score of 0** *(so no one ever cared to upvote it and likely never found it "useful")*
- are on an accepted answer *(so the answerer already got enough "thanks" by being awarded the checkmark)*

There are [73,885](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305423/test) comments that would be deleted. You can view a 50,000 sampling of them [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305424/test).

**Vote this question up** if you would like an employee to delete these 73,885 comments.

**Vote this question down** if you would not like an employee to delete these 73,885 comments.

Comment: I'm not sure 50,000 rows counts as a *"sampling"* - it's two thirds of the total! Why not add a `TOP 1000` in there?

Comment: I'm not really a big fan of automated deletion of content, even though the restrictions laid out here seem reasonable - thus +-0 from me. I do however think that the current manual removal of such comments, should they be flagged, is simply a waste of everybodys time. Maybe there could be a filter for "too chatty" comments which auto-deletes stuff like "thank you very much" (and minor variations), similar to how the offensive flag currently works.

Comment: Your sample query is looking for "thanks" not "thank" as your post lays out.

Comment: @l4mpi but even if they were auto deleted on one flag, it would still take one user slightly over 2 years to delete 73,885 of these thank you comments. (since limited to 100 comment flags a day). Whereas an employee could do this in 5 minutes.

Comment: How about an auto-delete routine that exterminates comments with five or more "too chatty" or similar flags?

Comment: @AdrianHHH  most comments can already be deleted with like 3 or more flags. The problem though, is that these flags go to moderators to handle!! So most times, they end up with having to take moderator time to handle them. The issue is that there are so many not useful comments and relatively few users that flag comments.

Comment: After a fairly decent look I'm not seeing anything of value that would be lost, in fact I wonder if the score zero is even necessary after changing to look at upvoted ones. Hopefully anyone that has upvoted a thanks comment (apart from the answerer) also upvoted the answer to indicate it was good.

Comment: While this is being discussed, please don't go through the list of comments and start mass-flagging them.  The mods thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to include a way of checking if there is a 'but' keyword in there as well... Something like: *"thanks for this, but it doesn't work for me since..."*

Comment: @jbutler483 as the comment has a max length of 25 characters, the "but" would be very very small, so I think that's covered.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 and what exactly do you gain by deleting those comments? What is the problem with them just existing? How many of those comments are on questions or answers that are actually visited often, as opposed to dead posts that nobody will ever see again? You complain about them taking moderator time - well here's the deal, _they don't take anybodys time if you don't flag them_. And IMO they are simply not problematic in 99% of cases. That's why I think it would be a better idea to do something agains the flood of trivial flags, rather than trying to proactively clean comments.

Comment: @Jordumus, [99 results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305447/test)

Comment: @l4mpi I think proactively cleaning comments would lessen the trivial flags since there would be no point in users flagging these types of trivial comments since an employee or the system would take care of them. We all know the current system isn't working. I posted this question to see how the community would feel about getting rid of these specific 73k comments easily, in a new way, without wasting user and moderator time, but only taking up 5 minutes of an employee's time. I think it's an obvious, huge advantage to all of us.

Comment: @l4mpi I see a problem with these useless comments just sitting there. It takes up space on the page, it could potentially hide more useful comments, and it waste's viewers time in reading them. It all adds up to a problem... one in which is very easily fixed. There are currently flag options/help-topics/meta threads  that state these comments should be flagged, so if the community would rather we just let all these types of comments sit there, than I'd propose someone start a feature-request to only have options for spam/offensive/other under the comment flag dialog.

Comment: I believe most flags on questions and answers add items to a review queue, only one flag adds the item to a moderator's queue. I am suggesting something similar for flags on comments. Some flags on comments could, when enough similar flags are raised, lead to a comment being auto-deleted. That would purge the unwanted comments and reduce the moderation load for comments.

Comment: The 'takes away space' argument only holds if there is something valuable on the page which loses visibility due to the comment. And changing your query to only take posts with >500 views into account reduces the number of results to ~32k (~45k for >200); meaning many are on low-view posts anyways (which lessens the chance they'll ever be flagged in the first place). Not that I think those comments are especially valuable, but too many comments are IMO wrongly deleted (not the "thanks" ones) - you'd set a dangerous precedent and would at least have to make sure there are no false positives.

Comment: Here's a graph of the comment count grouped by question views - as I thought, it's a pretty clear distribution and most of the comments are on low view questions: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305461/test#graph. Warning: might crash your browser as it's a graph of ~10k points. I'm not as proficient with the data explorer, if anybody knows how to further group those into bins it would be appreciated. Another interesting data point would be the distribution of those comments by question views per month.

Comment: A better summary: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305474/test Matching on all non-upvoted comments regardless of place or age: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305482/test

Comment: Strongly related: [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)

Comment: I can get behind this on the basis of preventing the necessity to flag them manually, and then those flags having to be reviewed. I don't have the internet points yet to actually be able to review stuff so I haven't felt any pain yet there - I reason this from the other perspective, being the "flaggee". I do flag questions when I see a need, I am training myself to also flag really poor answers, but I am very reluctant to flag comments. There are too many, and they are considered to be of far lesser importance anyway.

Comment: How about adding one more condition: only delete comments on posts where there are other comments. A "thank you" comment that is crowding out more useful comments is bad, but a "thank you" comment on its own is not so bad.

Comment: @Flimm If we were going to go down the automatic deletion route (and I'm not sure if we should), I think I'd prefer the opposite. If there are other comments then some of those may need clearing up along with the "thank you" comment. If it's the only comment on the post there's no worries about that.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think we're in agreement. :P

Comment: Sometimes thanks is meaningful, for example when correct/working answer is in a comment, does SO lacks a storage space? And I've never experienced any difficulties in simple overlooking of these "thanks"... anyway I'd made it as a warning to the commenter, before the comment is submitted, not as a mechanical censore.

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov These 73,885 comments are all on accepted answers, so unlikely that the answer was only left as a comment in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

### What I believe:

I believe your **idea** is great; however, automating the deletion of the comments defeats the purpose of our community driven "society" where we "clean" up after each other. By reading the rules and then contributing brings us closer together and work more efficiently.

I appreciate you posting that Data StackExchange showing us how "thank you" comments are definitely overused and overlooked. I am sure everyone is working on their [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal) badges! (make sure not to mass-flag! see moderator **bluefeet** comment)

Since my time using **Stackoverflow**, I used to write "thank you" comments quite often because I did not read the rules and I thought it was important to give short, fast and "thoughtful" feedback right away.(You can see some of my very old answers and comments.) I have later realized that this falls under **Compliments which do not add new information** and I have now stopped and started using **upvotes** instead.

The more time I spend on **StackOverflow** and the more time I spend reading the rules and flagging certain comments and questions, I have learned to differentiate between quality comments that *may* include a **thank you** but has actually added new information. Then I can make a clear decision whether or not to flag such comments. Obviously "thank you" comments in minimal amount of characters are most likely not adding any new information, I think it is important as a community to read and manually flag them if they are not abiding by the rules.

I have enjoyed my learning experience and I hope that this has helped make more sense of why **StackOverflow** is not already doing this.

### From StackOverflow:

> **When shouldn't I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an
>   existing one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or
>   up-vote a better answer if appropriate);
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

### Similar questions listed here:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261217/reject-comments-with-thanks-and-thank-you-with-a-tooltip-explaining-why
- [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)
- [Should "Thank you" comments be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged)
- [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment)

Comment: '...community driven "society" where we "clean" up after each other.' - A valid point in principle, but undermined by the +70K _probably_ useless thank you comments that haven't been cleaned up.

Comment: @cmannett85 Very true! We should all do our part and clean those up together.

Comment: "automating the deletion of the comments defeats the purpose of our community driven 'society'" I agree with that. But at this moment there is no way for the community to efficiently or realistically handle the backlog of comments that should be deleted. Thus, maybe it would be acceptable to ask the community if they'd be OK with specific types of comments being deleted. If a decent community consensus is reached, then let an employee delete them. This way we still have community input and things can actually get done.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 I have mentioned bluefeet's comment in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think my opinion would be that if you can positively identify redundant information, then getting rid of it would be no harm.

Whilst I can see the point that a 'thanks' doesn't do much harm, and it's a 'nice' sort of a comment - and on that basis, I'd suggest leaving it. The point is - we do ask people not to do it, and we do get moderators picking up flags to deal with useless comments.

So as such - delete 'em, and be done with it. Comments are supposed to be ephemeral anyway.