# Automatically block obvious "thank you" comments from being posted

Tags: feature-request, comments

I noticed that comments like "What have you tried?" are blocked from being posted, but "thank you very much" / "this works for me" comments are not blocked (and are found everywhere).

Is it possible to extend the comment-filtering mechanism to block "thank you" comments as well?

Comment: Related: [Comments can't contain that content - “What have you tried?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251309/11682469)

Comment: If you flag these kinds of comments, they'll usually get removed automatically.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it be better if they're prevented from appearing in the first place?

Comment: Kinda related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291213/11573842

Comment: IIRC some users run comment bots that flag comments that meet the criteria of deletion on a single flag. Of course, this will be good to have at a system level but I think it would be better if the author of the comments is also warned against writing such comments. That would deter them from writing them in the future. (The similar kinda warning we get when we write "What have you tried?"). Basically, don't just delete them, ask the author to not post them.

Comment: Perhaps the warning message could include a suggestion to mark the answer as accepted. Many newcomers say thanks rather than clicking the tick.

Comment: Frankly, that would be a bit hard to do properly (when going the "ban" route), unless only blatant cases are prevented from posting. A warning would be nice, though - I remember discussing that when SE tried to roll out a "thanks button" - this could educate users that do want to learn how the site works (those that do not care are irredeemable regardless). Such a warning could help to alleviate the problem of users "thanking" the poster instead of upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped them

Comment: Btw, [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) might be of interest here

Comment: If the warning message can encourage upvote/accept, it could also reduce the number of spurious comments asking for acceptance.

Comment: You'd want any sort of blocking/deterrence to be careful. I've seen quite a few comments that include some form of thanks along with how the answer helped (in some cases the answer was not a complete solution, and the comment included the additional steps needed).

Comment: I suppose those useful comments could be identified in some way (similar to how the auto-remove algorithm works for comment flags).

Comment: I probably belong to a minority group, but though I understand that this is a no-clutter-community, I believe that writing a simple "Thanks" reminds people we are still humang beings. So, IMHO, tolerating 'thanks' for a grace period and then flagging them remains the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I disagree.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni - they wouldn't be such a problem if people did not use them as substitutes for voting. I think everyone has a bunch of example posts with "thanks" comments, no votes and no accepts (can run a query if needed). They are also a waste of database usage (at a scale of SO it becomes tangible). Finally, they waste the time of curators. If not for the considerations of false positives, it would be an easy decision to block them outright.

Comment: most people find it polite and want to show theier gratitude. If you don't like flag them

Comment: @OlegValter Personally I think that the argument that such comments make user less likely to vote or accept is very insignificant based on my nine years experience with the site and many thousands of answers. I actually appreciate them as humanizing the effort put in. In rare instances where such a comment didn't prompt an acceptance they also make it more friendly to say *"Great! if it helped feel free to accept"*

Comment: I have been flagging these comments automatically for the past year and all the comments that I flagged automatically were completely useless. I would happily see such filter being implemented in SO because it works perfectly and is very easy to implement.

Comment: i never flag such comments, as i find the deletion of comments already far to massive and one or two thnx  is fine by me.