# Mother Function! Why was my "not constructive" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

I recently flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re/133327#comment-29137597) as not constructive. It reads:

> "mother function"! What I'm going to yell when I'm angry.

Perhaps I've missed something but I don't find this comment constructive. My flag was declined and I'm not sure why.

Could someone enlighten me? Is this comment constructive? Its fairly amusing, but *constructive*? I don't see how.

Comment: Why is it so problematic that it needs to be removed?

Comment: Is it any more or less problematic than a "Thank you" comment?

Comment: Thank you comments don't generally merit deletion...

Comment: I was under the impression [they do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258032/1555990)

Comment: Because it's a highly-upvoted, three-year-old comment. There are plenty of other comments to flag...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, there are plenty of other comments to flag. The age and number of votes surely doesn't change the constructiveness of this comment, does it?

Comment: It's a comment with 100 upvotes; are you targetting it for a particular reason instead of the other comments still on that post?  There are quite a few comments that could be edited into the answer and then removed.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I chose that comment over others because my knowledge of Javascript is limited and I don't feel I know enough to judge whether the others are constructive - considering they actually deal with Javascript and not just a humorous line in the answer ;)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Also, why should the number of upvotes determine a comment's constructiveness? I've flagged highly upvoted comments in the past without a decline. Shouldn't the comment's content trump its popularity?

Comment: Popularity is taken into account; and there's a higher bar to removing popular comments than there are not popular comments. It's purely an individual moderator choice.  The higher a comment rates, the more it's allowed to get away with.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that encourage more noise? I understand every flag is handled on a case-by-case basis and that moderator choice is the ultimate decider, but I maintain the comment in question is not constructive and deserved a flag; noise is noise regardless of its popularity, no?

Comment: So you think you can destroy somebody's contribution, favored by over a hundred other SO users, with just a single vote.  Keep looking for that Mother Function, you believe.

Comment: @HansPassant Destroy somebody's contribution? I'd like to think of it as cleaning up the site...

Comment: There are not a lot of comments reaching +100 and more, compared to all of the other comments, In fact, exactly [0.0036%](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/582191). Let's cut some slack... this isn't noise.

Comment: keep in mind that the bar is higher for popular comments, but it's generally only for comments that are orders of magnitude more popular than their brethren. We only have 1919 comments according to the data dump that have a score greater than 99, so it's not as if there are a lot of comments that we're talking about to begin with. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/582189/731271/comments-by-score

Comment: I thought [comments were temporary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Why keep them around even if they're popular? I'm not trying to be argumentative - I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Comments are "temporary" in that there is no guarantee they will be kept around, and they can be deleted if they become obsolete or are of low quality. It doesn't mean all comments that you happen to flag are fair game.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I have said the same thing countless times, however, perhaps not enough for it to be true. Hans notes that comments are "contributions" here a few comments up, Shog seems to think that quipy comments are okay in general, and I see a lot of passive aggressive comments all over the place that aren't removed. Do you think, if reflecting on the status of comments today, that it is possible comments are "permanent" (just as permanent as answers for example) and constitute "contribution"?

Comment: I've had a 100+ scored comment removed here on MSO, so I guess it's somewhat less consistent than most of the replies you're getting here would suggest.

Comment: Tag this [support]

Comment: Not constructive comment flags aren't constructive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I declined that flag, and maybe I made a bad call here. I was processing a series of comment flags at the time, and didn't spend a lot of time on this one. We generally don't worry too much about comment flags, aside from the "rude and abusive" ones or the occasional spam.

I know that [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) on Stack Overflow, but I'll sometimes leave highly-upvoted joke comments alone because I think they add a little character to the place. (As long as they're not offensive or insulting, of course.) I guess maybe I miss a little of the fun of the earlier days of the site. Sometimes they even add an interesting perspective on a question or answer.

This one doesn't really do that, or add much here. Because you've made a strong argument for why it should go, and it seems like others agree with you, I've deleted the comment. Don't worry about the declined comment flag, these don't work against you in the same manner as declined flags on posts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not really concerned about the decline itself, I just wanted to make sure I was flagging appropriately.

Comment: Well, your definition of a "strong argument" is rather different than mine. The only thing the question says is, "I don't find this comment constructive", which is a claim, not an argument. I'm not particularly invested on this particular comment, of course, but I see absolutely nothing wrong in general with leaving humorous comments in place. We only hate fun if it interferes with our core business of Q&A. Comments are a place where fun can be conditionally allowed. Jeff's blog post doesn't mention comments at all, in fact. Obsessing over "non-constructive" comments is extremely unproductive.

Comment: @CodyGray You may see it as "obsessing over non-constructive comments", but I choose to see it as "verifying my flagging behavior conforms to defined standards in hopes to avoid wasting our moderators' valuable and limited discretionary time", an endeavor I hope we can all agree is for the greater good, meaning this particular post is overall extremely productive in the long run.

Comment: I want to upvote this because you declined the flag, but I also want to downvote this because you then deleted the comment. No votes for you!

Comment: [All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_work_and_no_play_makes_Jack_a_dull_boy), sprinkling a little humour here and there to make work interesting and enjoyable should not be seen as _not constructive_ when done in moderation, IMO.