# Repeated thank you comments

Tags: discussion

How should we deal with users who repeatedly [break comment rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged) (most likely because they didn't read the rules)?

I've been tracking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6381081/martin-aj) user for about a month or so, and even though I flagged 50+ comments of him, [he keeps posting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6381081/martin-aj?tab=activity) the same in every answer made on each of his questions:

> +1 upvoted
>
> thank you ... upvoted

and stuff like that.

I **don't have anything against this particular user**. Actually, had I tracked all users who I've flagged because of thank you post I'm pretty sure I would have a long list of users by now.

What should we do to prevent this behavior? IMO, if they don't get any sort of visual notification, I doubt they'll ever realize that goes against SO rules.

Comment: Flag, move on??

Comment: Well i've seen worst that that, and they just tring to notify all the users answered their questions about the same thing in a hope that someone will reply the quickest as possible. I also see lot's of `thank you` and `+1 upvoted` on SO, but it's not systematic with this user

Comment: Flag, and @reply to the user to [read the rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged).

Comment: Not worry about it?  What harm is it doing, how is it making the site harder to use?  There's far more important things to work on.  With that guy in particular I'd be far more worried about the pure volume of questions he needs to ask than him adding thank you comments.

Comment: It tends to help to let a user know that his behavior is being discussed at meta.  Done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't track a user due to specific behavior and specially not for months.

It is fine to flag comments that are too chatty or obsolete when you encounter them on a post. But when you decide to cast some flags, handle everything you find on that page: Close vote the question, fix the layout, spelling and grammar, vote on the posts, flag non-answers and purge all comments that are not helping to make the post more clear or address specific issues in the post.

You can leave a friendly reminder ("be nice") to the OP that instead of *thanks* they can use the vote and accept buttons and those mechanism are there so we can focus on content.

tl;dr; do as Braiam said: flag and move on.

Comment: "I wouldn't track a user due to specific behavior and specially not for months." — did I give the impression of being that paranoic? all I did was to keep the user in bookmarks and checked him whenever I noticed the bookmark was still there (maybe twice or so) since I  noticed a long list of thank you comments the first time I came across him. Anyway, thank you. I think a friendly reminder can do the trick as most of you suggested already.

Comment: @zurf it read like that, yes. But if anyone is paranoic about moderating a user it is me. In the chatroom where I'm a room owner we clearly state that we moderate posts not users. And we find almost on a daily basis how hard it is to stay away from that. If it is really an abusive pattern then the best thing to do is to raise a custom flag and explain to the mod what is going on. The mod has all the tools to judge and the authority to address the behavior of users. I agree with you; sometimes a simple nudge is all that is needed to make users aware and stop them from doing whatever went wrong

Comment: @pnuts I don't see how removing comments would be in violation of the "be nice" policy. I see more users making links between  voting/editing/moderation and "be nice". Those are really different things, let's reserve "be nice" for when we engage with real people. Use our moderation options for how we want this site to look like: cleaned-up, high-quality, no-chit-chat.

Comment: @pnuts I'm not sold nor do I fancy declined comment flags because *user was new* and thousands of thanks, appreciated and what not on every frigging answer because we want to "be nice". That feels a bit as the discussion about leaving *Thanks in  advance* in a post. Removing it would not be nice. I'm not in that camp. I admit a lot needs to be fixed before we all "be nice", even my own way of engaging with (new) users but what you ask for shouldn't be a priority now and once we fixed all the other "be nice" challenges it remains to be seen if your proposal still needs addressing.