# Sudden interest in an old answer

Tags: support, comments, reputation

I posted this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28838789/1767412 in March 2015 - over 2 years ago and never received a single comment.  Now suddenly in the last 24 hours I've received three completely unrelated (positive) comments from different users.

Also, the answer appears to have been upvoted twice but I've received no additional rep that I can see.

So this is a 2 part question:

1. Why the sudden increase in attention?  In 800 days online 3 comments come at once? Just a coincidence?
2. Why no rep for upvotes?

Comment: The answer was converted to a community wiki post, some time ago. You don't get (/lose) rep for votes on those.

Comment: Must've been a part of an assignment a teacher somewhere has given out to her students. It's possible that all three commentors are classmates. /s

Comment: That makes a nice change.  Usually, nothing happens on my old stuff for ages, then pairs of downvotes appear at the same time each day for a week:)

Comment: FYI: all three comments were variations of "thanks" and I've cleaned them up. ["Thank you" comments are considered noise and should be flagged as "too chatty"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258032/229044).

Comment: That question could definitely use a clean up. So many duplicate answers there.

Comment: I think it's not as odd as when someone suddenly shows up and accepts an answer you gave them a long time ago. It makes me wonder what was going on the meantime, like maybe user4873926 had been going through some bad times, but finally decided to get their life back on track, starting with that programming problem they were having trouble with just before "the incident".

Comment: @Don'tPanic - haha!  I've had that exact same experience and thought.

Comment: @Don't Panic: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/695493/answers-that-took-way-too-long-to-accept-all-users http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/695498/answers-that-took-way-too-long-to-accept-single-user

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of possible explanations for this sort of thing. The following list is by no means exhaustive, but it gives you some ideas:

1. Your answer was shared elsewhere, gaining a significant number of views as a result. Notably, a significant portion of these views were from Stack Overflow users who not only have voting privileges, but also commenting privileges.
2. The question you answered was linked to from a fresh new question or a question that is currently popular (either as a duplicate target, or simply via a regular hyperlink). For questions that aren't already popular duplicate targets you can discover this in the Linked section on the sidebar. For questions that *are* popular duplicate targets, this becomes much harder to ascertain.
3. The question you answered was bumped — probably not the case here since its last activity was "1 month ago", but it might well explain sudden activity on other old answers for anyone else looking.

Given that the question you answered has literally *dozens* of answers, and yours isn't that high up (although it's in the first page, which is something), it's most likely that your specific answer was shared. There are no new comments on any of the other answers, particularly not the accepted answer, which is quite unusual indeed, even if most of the answers likely received upvotes over the same recency.

The upvotes did not award any reputation because the question is a community wiki, and answers to wiki questions are themselves wikis and therefore do not contribute to your reputation.