# Is "Very crafty. Nice work." a comment that should be kept

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I flagged a comment as "No longer needed" that just said "Very crafty. Nice work." yesterday and was really surprised when the flag was declined. Because I thought that this was just an equivalent to a "Good answer (+1)" comment.

I assume that the moderator reviewing the flag just accidentally misclicked. But before I flag the comment again I wanted to make sure that it wasn't a mistake on my part.

Comment: Good question (+1)

Comment: Just wait until there is enough signal to compensate, like the post getting the Nice Answer badge.

Comment: That's a great comment @Servy (+1)

Comment: I would say the mods have enough on their plate to worry about positive comments...

Comment: Good discussion, everyone. Glad we talked about this.

Comment: Seriously...who cares? Is that comment actually hurting you?

Comment: @CodyGray No, but if I shouldn't flag such comments I would like to know about it. :)

Comment: @Icepickle In that case why is there a "no longer needed" comment flag? If it were just about negative comments it would be enough to keep "rude/abusive" and "custom flag"?

Comment: @MSeifert sure that would make more sense, however maybe it's a comment that later got added as info into the post, or contains outdated information. I understand that flagging can make sense, but honestly, I don't see any harm in having such a comment

Comment: The main purpose of "no longer needed" is for comments that are actually no longer needed. Like comments suggesting to add information into a question, and then that information has been added. Or comments asking for clarification on an answer, and then that clarification has been added into the answer. You can also use "no longer needed" on "+1 good answer" comments, but as the answers to the dupe point out, there might be cases where such comments add value. I'm not sure if that's true of "crafty" or not, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @CodyGray Understood, but there's a difference between "that's too complicated" and "that's crafty", the first is an (unspoken) request to simplify the answer while the second one is ... well ... chatty. Thanks for pointing me to the duplicate though. So you actually say that the flag was correctly declined (that's what I want to know)?

Comment: Well, there is no "correct" here. It's a gut call. The comment is not obviously unconstructive or noise, but it's not obviously useful and praiseworthy, either. So when you flag these, you're going to get mixed results. There isn't a hard rule here. Unless we get a bot to delete all of the comments. ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, there *is* a correct answer.  Comments that are noise are supposed to be deleted when they're flagged, not kept around when they add nothing of value.  The duplicate doesn't apply here in the slightest; the duplicate is saying that a comment that points out that an answer is too hard to understand is a useful criticism of an answer, and provides value in helping a question author improve it.  This comment provides no useful information on how the author can improve the answer.

Comment: Everyone take note: Servy's gut says the comment is noise and should be deleted. Oh, and look---the comment is gone now, so maybe we can all go do something more productive.

Comment: I too had the situation 2 days before. The comment flag declined but the comment deleted anyway

Comment: @CodyGray No, my gut is irrelevant here. The site's rules say that comments that are noise should be removed, and that moderators should remove comments that are noise when flagged, rather than ignoring the rules, falsely claiming they don't exist, and just doing whatever they want instead of following the rules.

Comment: There is no objective rule anywhere that says that comment is noise, so accusing me and other moderators of not doing our jobs is ludicrous.

Comment: @CodyGray There *is* a rule that says that a if a comment is noise, and isn't helpful, it should be removed.  You said that that comment wasn't helpful, and wasn't adding anything of value.  If you had said that you felt that the comment added useful information that can be used to improve the post, and therefore chose to not delete it, *then* you'd be following the rules.  Saying that the comment *isn't* helpful, but that you don't want to delete it *anyway*, just because you don't want to, *isn't* following the rules.

Comment: Oh, look everyone!  @CodyGray has learned that obsolete/too chatty comment flags are the most annoying and useless flags evar!  Our little mod is growing up *sniff*.

Comment: Given that the _no longer needed_ flag is described as _This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary._ I would say that flagging the comment was appropriate. The flag name should not _dictate_ its usage, considering they merged different flags into a single one.

Comment: I think it's a matter of context. If some unconnected passer-by posts this as a comment, by all means delete it. Not so if the OP posts this as an explanation why they chose this answer over others.

Comment: I could imagine cases where the comment "Very crafty." could indeed be useful. Let's say we have a post with 5 answers, all are correct and get equally upvoted. However, one post is especially "crafty" in the sense that it is elegantly solving the issue, it might be worth noting that as a comment.

Comment: Would you seriously go back and flag that comment again?  If the moderators go back and check your flag again and decide to go back and delete the comment does that mean anything?  Should the first moderator be removed along with the comment?  Should there be a huge moderator meeting and training session?  If there are rules that are inflexible is the product better than if the rules have a little bit of 'give' to them?  How would that be better?  If the rules were meant to be rigidly enforced then there would need to be one GRAND moderator who had the final say in all cases...Not a good idea.

Comment: @Drt You misunderstood my intention. I would only consider flagging it again in case it was "declined" because of a misclick. I only asked the question because **I wasn't sure if I should flag such a comment** - not to educate or "blame" moderators.

Comment: I just went and did a bunch of reading on this and came across discussion about using a "custom flag" where you can provide some sort of explanation or suggestion/question about why you are posting the flag...that may actually get you the answer you are looking for because it didn't happen here.

Comment: @CodyGray he's right y'know. You can't claim that all *useless* comments must be deleted and then say *we're not justified in reporting a useless comment*. Those two statements contradict each other.

Comment: It would be a useful comment if it added *exactly what*  is "crafty" about the answer; preferably in relation to the other not-so-crafty answers/comments.

Comment: @Typhon The issue is whether or not that comment is useless. That is the thing I'm claiming is subjective. [ImportanceOfBeingEarnest has already explained a scenario](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354898/is-very-crafty-nice-work-a-comment-that-should-be-kept?cb=1#comment503752_354898) in which a comment like that could be useful.

Comment: @CodyGray well then you're just being generally wish-washy. *In this thread*, you stated the comment was useless but felt the flag was unwarranted and that you didn't want to have to delete it. By all means, you're entitled to being lazy but at least be consistent and don't deny flags that you even believe are useful... please.

Comment: Can we get a metric for the amount of hand-wringing that is done over comments on this site?  If every useless comment on this site was flagged, there would be no comments.

Comment: It seems people are misreading or misunderstanding my comments. Maybe the sentence was too complex. I absolutely *did not* state that the comment was "useless". I said: *"The comment is not obviously unconstructive or noise, but it's not obviously useful and praiseworthy, either."* If you read that again, slowly, it should be clear what I actually said, despite the syntactical complexity. The comment isn't obviously good, but it's not obviously bad, either. Which is quite the opposite of "useless". @Typhon

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Does it meet at least one of the "This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary." criteria? **Yes.**

Is it worth your time to flag it and the mod's time to handle the flag? **Probably not.**

There are lots of things like that in life.

Comment: But why would a mod take time to handle it to decline it?

Comment: @Winter: Oh, I expect *that* was likely just human error.

Comment: @Winter because if the flag was not declined many more useless flags would follow.

Comment: @user000001 What's the idea behind making available a flagging criteria met by useless flags?

Comment: @Winter Good question, my understand is that the chatty reason is used as a catch-all phraze to justify random comment deletions. If all chatty comments were flagged, the number is moderators that would be needed would increase by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: @user000001 Don't you agree that's something that should be changed by design instead of declining flag to "discourage" having more flags of that kind? Ignoring them would be a better idea too.

Comment: @Winter sure, but that has problems of its own. People would wonder why some flags are never handled. I don't think that there is a good solution overall...

Comment: @user000001 I think that even if there's no perfect solution, we can still compare solutions to each other and take the least stupid one. Declining it being the most stupid one.

Comment: @Winter Once it's in the queue, the mods have to do *something* with it. They can't just let the number of unhandled flags grow indefinitely.

Comment: @jpmc26 They could just delete the flags instead of declining them one by one without looking at it. Especially if there's a mod spamming decline by hand on every flag, that's dumb. But I didn't say ignoring them was the best idea, the best idea is to change the criterias to something more appropriate for what the mods are willing to handle. Another good idea would be to let non moderators handle too chatty flags/no longer used flags. There's lots of good idea, I'm not saying I'm fit to decide on one. What I'm pointing out is that declining them isn't the action that should be taken.

Comment: @Winter what kind of nonsense is this? mods, aren't spamming, if anything the people doing it are those that flag comments that are not particularly problematic. Please explain the difference between a declined/ignored/deleted flag, if the supposedly problematic comment is not deleted anyway. It is like most people in this thread are more interested in not having declined flags on their profile, than on helping the moderators delete truly problematic content.

Comment: @Winter You're not thinking this through. There's no practical benefit to what you're proposing, and it doesn't make logical sense anyway. 1) Flags aging away leaves junk in the queue for a long time. 2) There is no logical difference between marking a flag as disputed or declined and "deleting" it. 3) A moderator still has to review the flag to decide what to do with it even if there was a "delete" option. 4) If there even are any automatic consequences to declined flags, the thresholds are high enough that you'd only encounter them if you very regularly raise bad flags.

Comment: @jpmc26 My first point is about designing a good system. My second one is about how to live with a bad system. Declining a good flag because there's too much of them is a bad option for reasons I already stated. Letting flags age away is also a bad option but not as bad as declining good flags. Also what are you opposing? In the 4 points you made, 1 is about aging away flags, another is about deleting them and the 2 others are about how declining them is not _that_ bad so it should _obviously_ be the option. Who cares about the queue being full of junk? _Does it actually hurt you?_

Comment: It's just like telling to your volunteers they are doing a bad job even if they are following your rules because there's too much for them for you as a manager. Maybe there's no difference for you because you are gonna get less volunteers either way but for the people, there's a big difference between getting declined and getting ignored. One lets him think he is doing a bad job while the other indicates you might be busy right now.

Comment: @Winter Your idea doesn't create a "good system," though. It puts the burden on mods to *actively ignore* a lot of flags sitting in their queue *after spending the time to determine they need ignoring*. That is not a good thing. The flags should be handled and then cleared out. Flags should be declined because they shouldn't have been raised in the first place. Flags on comments that aren't causing problems shouldn't be raised in the first place.

Comment: @jpmc26 Of course they should, but not by clicking the decline button repeatedly. If a mod is about to do something that stupid, he should just do nothing instead (and hope other mods clears the queue). The aging away is the worst thing that could happen but is still way better than declining it. Flag that meets the criteria should be raised, otherwise the criteria should be changed. "Causing problem" is really subjective and this is why having criterias is a good thing.

Comment: @Winter No one is "clicking the decline button repeatedly."

Comment: @jpmc26 I also think it is like so but how do you want a mod to clear the queue faster by declining then? If he takes as much time to decline it than to handle it properly, he should just handle it properly. As I asked and as I was answered, it was likely a human error, because there is no reason for a mod to decline it deliberately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151987/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-winter).

Comment: Lots of misinformation in the comments here. Comment flags, which are what we're talking about, can *only* be marked "helpful" (which means a mod deleted the comment that you flagged) or "declined" (which means a mod chose not to delete the comment that you flagged). That's it. That's all we can do. We can't "dispute"/"delete" them, we can't mark them "helpful" and not delete the comment. So stop obsessing over the results of comment flags. They don't matter. And making the claim that mods should just delete all the comments to process the flags faster is...stupid and quite counter-productive.

Comment: *"while having it ignored/aged away means the charge of work for mods is too big"* No, it doesn't mean that at all. Flags that age away are those that aren't handled by moderators (e.g., flags that a question needs to be closed). If a flag goes into a queue processed by moderators, it isn't going to age away. We're not *that* far behind on doing our jobs. If we just let comment flags age away, there'd be no real point in having them. We make a decision on each one of them: delete the comment or not delete the comment. It's a very simple decision; we don't overthink it, so you shouldn't either.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not saying that flags should be aged away manually or deleted, I'm saying declining them because there's too much of them is so dumb it would be better not doing your job (aka letting them age away). _So stop obsessing over the results of comment flags. They don't matter._ You may don't care about what you tell to your volunteers but the volunteers care about what is being said to them.

Comment: @Winter: You seem to be under the impression Code Gray is an SE employee. As far as I know (for instance, from his/her profile), that's not the case. He/she **is** one of those volunteers you're talking about, though.

Comment: Nope, not an employee. Just a volunteer [monkey with a gun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5dp.png). My first name is actually "Cody" though. Parents chose it before they knew I would write any code. Common mistake around here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 16):

“*Very crafty. Nice work.*” alone is generally not a comment that should be kept.

To mention that an answer is valuable in the absolute, use a +1 vote.

This is the same as with [thank you comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged/258032#258032):

> Yes, typically we do consider these types of comments as noise and should be removed. If you see them, then flag them as such. --bluefeet♦

"*Very crafty. Nice work...*" could fit as part of a comment if there is value in the rest of the comment.

[Note on comments in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757):

> [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). You should not expect them to be around forever: Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion. In reality, many obsolete or chatty comments remain untouched due to the high volume of comments posted, but this does not mean that they can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future. --[Laura](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/166017/laura)

Comment: I'd just like to take a moment to disagree with the first line of this answer. IF the comment had been "Good answer. Nice work", then I would agree, but specifically saying "Very crafty" does add more to the sentiment than simply "Good answer". It implies that the answer is a particularly unusual or creative way of solving the problem. Assuming that fact wasn't otherwise obvious, then the comment is adding a valuable extra piece of information about the answer, which may be useful for others when selecting which answer to use.

Comment: @Simba you already help others selecting the answer by voting. Not sure how a unusual way of solving a problem (+1) is a better answer than a very great answer (+1).

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: That's what made it comment-worthy, not just vote-worthy.  (At least in the mind of the person who wrote that comment).  Since being "crafty" doesn't automatically make an answer good, and can actually be a bad thing for maintainability, commenting *positively* on the craftiness is a way of saying that you think it was justified and/or a good idea in that particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Being "crafty" doesn't automatically make something good, and can actually be a bad thing for code maintainability.

Commenting positively *on the craftiness* is a way of saying that you think it was justified and/or a good idea in that particular case.

There's more to this comment than just a generic "nice work" that isn't specific to the answer at all.

Other answers to this meta question have addressed the issue of whether it's worth the time to be strict about no useless comments when they're not cluttering things up for useful comments.  I could easily see a combination of both reasons leading to a mod declining a flag.

Comment: I believe this is a greatly undervalued answer. Being informed by domain experts that a particular way of doing something is *crafty*, which often amounts to a not so good way of doing someting, is priceless insight.

Answer (score -6):

Flags are for problems. Problems surrounding comments include:

- Comments that contain important information about the question or answer. The answerer can't answer properly without all the info, and a reader can't use an answer properly without all the info. The worst example of this is when info that *changes the answer* is scattered across replies from the OP on the answers. The second worst is when important info is buried down among a long chain that someone would have to read through. (Note that the important info should be *edited in* before such a comment is flagged.)
- Comments that are inspiring a long chain of other comments, which distract from the main content, may hide important information, and (as a very minor issue) may cause clutter in list pages by bumping.
- Comments that inflame, which would typically result in a long chain of other comments if the site never did anything about them, which again makes finding important info in them harder.

So which of these does that comment fall into? If it's all by itself, none of them. On SO, it's the question and answer content that's prime. When a comment doesn't interfere with that, no problem exists to solve.

Don't waste moderators' time on a non-problematic compliment. The same goes for, "Thanks," comments. (I understand that much of the community opposes this mindset, so I won't be surprised when this answer is heavily downvoted. But I find that to be unreasonably pedantic, so I'm posting this anyway.)

Comment: "I understand that much of the community opposes this mindset" - but it's not just a 'community mindset' thing. The name of the flag - *all* that we as users have to go on - is 'no longer needed // This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary.' Note that this text does *not* talk about a 'problem' at all! The system clearly intends that commends that are 'obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary' *should* be flagged - otherwise why have a flag that says that??

Comment: @AakashM Obsolete exists because important info should be edited in (as the answer says). The other possible reasons are there because sometimes a comment can inspire an entire chain of responses without being rude. Note that "chatty" and "unnecessary" are extremely subjective, as well. It just has to say *something* on the flag text. The better question is, "Where is moderator time most effectively spent?" Is it cleaning up a bunch of comments that aren't hurting anything, or closing/deleting problematic questions and long comment chains?