# Can mods also see the answers while they're reviewing comment flags on a question?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I flagged a couple of comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375389/why-does-var-dump-show-filename-and-line-number) as "no longer needed" because I thought they were obsolete. The comments don't seem to contain any information that isn't in the accepted answer, but the flags were declined.

I'm not asking this question to complain about the flags being declined; it's not a big deal and I don't like complaining. But it made me curious about how flag-handling works. I know mods have a ton of them to deal with so they can't spend that much time on each one. But now with just one flag reason, it seems like it can't be as obvious why something was flagged in some cases.

I wondered if the flags were declined because they were handled like one of the old "not constructive" flags, and the comments *were* constructive, at least initially. It really doesn't look like there's anything wrong with them unless you can see that they're included in the answer, and therefore obsolete, but I don't know if the answers are even displayed while a flag on a comment on a question is being reviewed.

If they aren't, what would be the best way to indicate that I'm flagging a question comment because it's obsolete due to being included in the answer? An "in need of moderator intervention" flag seems like overkill, but "no longer needed" may not be expressive enough in this case.

On the other hand, should I just avoid flagging comments like that in the first place? Maybe I'm operating under false assumptions and they are actually useful even though they seem redundant to me (or at least not *unuseful* enough to waste people's time getting rid of them)?

Comment: I always flag comments under the assumption that the mod can judge the validity of the flag by the comment content alone. So as soon as they have to go wonder: *why is this flagged* you risk a decline. In those cases I do use a custom flag to explain the context. I assume they re-verify if they agree with the context and with my flag. If possible I prefer to have all comments removed (which is achieved with a custom flag on the post) but the cut-off is at 5 comments or more. I sometimes cherry-pick (so remove all comments, except the last one)

Comment: @rene thanks for the input. I had kind of a bad feeling when I flagged them, actually. I've been trying to change my flagging habits recently, after a post in the mod election announcement got me thinking. I think I'm still not not quite doing it right.

Comment: In case it helps here is a sample sceenshot of my comment flag history: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckbB2.png where you can see I use both canned reasons and custom flags on a single post to get comments removed. To request for a nuke all comments under a post I have a user script: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/flag-comments.user.js

Comment: @rene that screenshot makes me wonder if I'm being too cautious about using mod flags. I sort of considered them as only for extenuating circumstances, but the ones that are marked helpful there seem fairly commonplace.

Comment: (Not intending that as critical toward your flagging, just curious.)

Comment: I flag whatever I come across that served their goal. I don't hold back on that.

Comment: *"Maybe I'm operating under false assumptions and they are actually useful even though they seem redundant to me (or at least not unuseful enough to waste people's time getting rid of them)?"* Yeah, do consider this. Comments are easy to ignore for those who are uninterested, so leaving one or two that are arguably "no longer needed" in place is not really that big of a deal. Sometimes there is meaning to be found in a comment complimentary of an answer (e.g., if it explains why), and sometimes there is enlightenment in reading a train of thought. Better we don't obsess over comment cleanup.

Comment: Moderators don't have the time to investigate flags, so trying to do cleanup like this is not really likely to succeed. You have to jump through too many hoops to get done what you thought "flag a comment" might have otherwise accomplished.

Comment: @Cody yeah, I get that this is really not a big deal. I like the editing philosophy of "fix everything about the post" and sometimes it's tempting to try to apply it to things outside the post as well. It's not that easy for some of us to not obsess over details sometimes, but I'm trying. I don't want to misuse the tools I've been given, though. I'd already pretty much decided not to flag stuff like that again after those were declined, and I was mostly just asking this because I was curious how it worked.

Comment: I'm just getting pretty darn tired of the constant Meta covfefe over comments. The site has some significant quality problems, but comments are *not* where they're at. Focus on what will actually make a noticeable difference.

Comment: On a slightly related note, why did you go through Meta and delete all of your comments? Some of them were arguably just noise, but plenty of the ones you deleted seemed to provide useful and relevant insights and had received a number of upvotes by the community in recognition of that fact. Noisy comments are a problem; useful comments are *not* a problem and *don't* need to be deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Cody. I wasn't trying to cause any trouble. I didn't realize that would be noticeable. I've just been thinking a lot recently and really reevaluating how I want to participate here, and thought it might be easier for me to change some of my habits if I let go of some things and cleaned my slate to some extent. I'll be more selective about what I remove.

Comment: The irony did occur to me that you probably thought you were cleaning up after yourself to save moderators the trouble. The system raises automatic flags when users destroy potentially valuable content, so this did come to our attention. It's usually someone cleaning up a bunch of unneeded noise, so I usually don't think anything of it, but several of the comments you deleted were things I thought added value, so I wasn't really sure what was going on. I'm not sure why you're recently experiencing such a crisis of conscience. There's nothing wrong with your participation as far as I can tell.

Comment: You went on another comment deleting spree.... Not sure what's happening here and why. Your attempt at "cleaning up" is making all of those discussions impossible to follow because it's leaving a bunch of orphaned comments that reply to yours or otherwise build off of what you said. That isn't helping anyone. And I don't really see how the comments of yours were ever hurting anything. Please stop vandalizing content, or your account may be suspended.

Comment: @CodyGray I apologize again. After your last comment, I thought I was being more careful to only delete things that weren't upvoted (or were only upvoted because people thought they were funny), and hadn't been meaningfully responded to. I'm not trying to vandalize anything. I didn't think the comments were hurting anything, I just didn't want them to be associated with me. I'll leave it alone.

Comment: Are you afraid that people will think you're funny?

Comment: @CodyGray I think I am kind of funny, and I'm okay with that. I just don't really want that to be part of my participation here any more. I'll stop trying to remove that from the past, though. I really don't want to do any harm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As moderator on another Stack Exchange site, I can say moderators see just the comment being flagged, in the page showing all raised flags. There is a link for seeing the comment and the post for which the comment was posted, but I would not expect that moderators also check every answer for a question to verify if the comment was posted as answer too.

As moderator, I would understand the *no longer needed* flag for a question's comment as saying *the comment is not longer needed because the information requested from this comment has been added to the question* or *the comment is not longer needed because the information given from this comment has been already added to the question*.

If you are flagging a comment because there is an answer saying what the comment says, flag it for moderation attention, explaining there is an answer that says the same things.
It could be the comment is not removed, if the answer was posted from another user, but I would not expect the flag to be dismissed as not helpful.

Comment: That's correct; we just see disembodied flagged comments, independent of all context. I am probably the only moderator who processes comment flags by navigating to the post so I can see them in context, and I mostly do that (as required by my OCD) to ensure that I preserve the "flow" of discussion if/when I delete comments. If deleting an individual comment would disrupt the flow of discussion, and I want to preserve related comments, then I won't delete it. We can't mark a comment flag as "helpful" and *not* delete the comment, so all we can do is decline.

Comment: And while a custom flag is very useful for explaining things like why the comment is no longer needed, it *does* require that we take the flagger's word for it. Although most flaggers are quite reliable, remember that virtually *anyone* can raise flags, and not everyone is honest. So we do have to be careful with blind trust. [Will beat me to the punch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354898/is-very-crafty-nice-work-a-comment-that-should-be-kept#comment503356_354898), but he's correct: I already think that far too much ado is being made over comments and their flagging.

Comment: By explaining things, I meant _point me to the answer that is saying what the comment is saying_. I too check the post for which the flagged comment was posted, but I think that hoping moderators check every answer too is bit too far.

Comment: @CodyGray You are not the only one who navigates to posts. I think it's quite sensible, but I'm biased because I do it.